# Power cut while driving

Tags: vw, power, jetta, tdi

I was wondering if you can advise regarding an issue with a vw jetta 2.0 tdi 140 bhp 2006.

While driving on the motorway with 70 mph the car is loosing power like going into limp mode. After pulling onto the hard shoulder, the power just cuts off and will not want to restart. After a few minutes it will start and work fine. I had the car checked with a diagnostic reader and even been into the garage but no faults could be found. Also, I had the EGR cleaned, but it still has the issue with the car cutting off power. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the fuel filter changed? Also, check the fuel pumps for proper pressure. This sounds like the fuel pump(s) is not keep up with demand.

Comment: Power cuts off? Mechanically? Electrically?

Comment: the power cuts of mechanically

Comment: I did not had the fuel filter changed. i will check the fuel pump. Thank you

Comment: Check the fuel pump relay, it may be failing when too much power is applied, if not that then the fuel pump regulator then look at the fuel pump power supply, then the fuel pump itself

Comment: Had a similar issue, and as hello motto suggested, mine was the fuel pump relay. $40 at Autozone.